# What is the % sign in java and how does it work? (not modulo!)

Tags: java, jvm, logback

For example, in logback's Syslogappender:

```
String getPrefixPattern() {
          return "%syslogStart{" + getFacility() + "}%nopex{}";
}
```

Likewise the conversion words/characters in a PatternLayout (`%t` for a thread).

What are these? Variables? If so, what type?

Whatever they are, somehow the JVM changes them into, respectively, a thread identifier, and info related to the syslog protocol. I'd like to know how.

Furthermore, how can I find out what message `%syslogStart` gets converted into?

Comment: The JVM doesn't do anything with them. The classes concerned do, in ways that are specified in their Javadoc.

Comment: Classes don't do anything at all unless they're executed in a JVM...

Answer (score 1):

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

"Each conversion specifier starts with a percent sign (%) and is followed by optional format modifiers and a conversion character...."

So the %syslogStart{facility string} seems to determine what facility this log is written as, though this is directly related tot he Patternlayout class in Java. It's not that the JVM does anything with the %, but that it's an identifier, seems to be handled by some other process.

http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/net/SyslogAppenderBase.html
 "The **Facility** option must be set one of the strings KERN, USER, MAIL,
DAEMON, AUTH, SYSLOG, LPR, NEWS, UUCP, CRON, AUTHPRIV, FTP, NTP, AUDIT,
ALERT, CLOCK, LOCAL0, LOCAL1, LOCAL2, LOCAL3, LOCAL4, LOCAL5, LOCAL6,
LOCAL7. Case is not important."